# copying text from web to Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, copy-paste, text-formatting

I have some problems with my Word, usually when I was pasting some text from web, Word also saved format of the text and backgrounds but after I changed some settings and lost this ability of Word, can somebody tell me how can I get this feature back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click the Office button.
2. Click the Word Options button.
3. Click Advanced on the left side of the window.
4. Scroll down to "Cut, copy, and paste".
5. Check "Show Paste Options buttons".
6. Profit.